# Row height setting is not reflected correctly in dash-bootstrap-components

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I want to change row height using dash-bootstrap-components, but it is not reflected correctly on the page.

Specifically, even if I execute the code posted below, I will see a page like the one below.

[image]

But the simple structure of the page is as follows

- Whole page: height as 95% of view point, background color as grey
- First line: one column in `html.H1`, `className="h-10"`
- Line 2: 2 columns in `html.Div`, `className="h-40"`
- Line 3: 2 columns in `html.Div`, `className="h-40"`

In the code, the overall size of the page is set to 95% of the view point and the background color to grey, which I can see reflected in the following figure.

H1 element with "Title" is also 10% of the total size (`className="h-10"`), which is exactly as set, but the height of the second and subsequent lines is not as set.

I saw the following discussion at the beginning, and I think my code implements the same way.
https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/issues/286

These were not resolved by refreshing the page or restarting the server.
How can I get the height of each row to reflect the size I specify?

Thank you.

here is my source code

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html, dcc
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = dbc.Container(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            dbc.Col(
                html.H1("タイトル"),
                width=12,
                style={"height": "100%", "background-color": "pink"},
            ),
            className="h-10"
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    html.Div("This is column 1"),
                    width=8,
                    style={"height": "100%", "background-color": "red"},
                ),
                dbc.Col(
                    html.Div("This is column 2"),
                    width=4,
                    style={"height": "100%", "background-color": "green"},
                ),
            ],
            className="h-40",
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dbc.Col(
                    html.Div("This is column 3"),
                    width=8,
                    style={"height": "100%", "background-color": "blue"},
                ),
                dbc.Col(
                    html.Div("This is column 4"),
                    width=4,
                    style={"height": "100%", "background-color": "cyan"},
                ),
            ],
            className="h-40",
        ),
    ],
    style={"height": "95vh", "background-color": "grey"},
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Width and height utilities are generated from the $sizes Sass map in _variables.scss. Includes support for 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%, and auto by default. Modify those values as you need to generate different utilities here.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/sizing/

So the sizes you've specified (like: `h-40` are not supported by default).

---

You can simply set the height of each row to a percentage using its `style` property or via css files, no utility functions needed

```
dbc.Row(
  dbc.Col(
    html.H1("タイトル"),
    width=12,
    style={"height": "100%", "background-color": "pink"},
  ),
  style={"height": "10%"}
),
```